# как обновить заголовок колонки

Tags: java, swing, jtable

есть таблица, в которую выводятся данные посредством модели, для колонок также есть модель со своим рендерером, в таблице автоматическое изменение размера колонок при изменении колонок (добавлении/удалении изменении названия колонки) данные в таблице обновляются посредством метода модели fireTableStructureChanged(), тут все работает, но соответственно, если изменять руками ширину колонок, то fireTableStructureChanged() это дело аннулирует в исходное состояние..

прочитал, что если выставить таблице table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false); то это помогает, действительно, ширины колонок сохраняются, но при изменении заголовка/имени колонки, она остается неизмененной, собственно, вопрос как можно на хидер повлиять ?

пробовал и так и сяк - имя колонки не меняется, есть какой-то простой способ это решить, чтобы не добавлять на все манипуляции свой резайзер колонок ?

Comment: хотя бы идейно подскажите, придется исходники свинга ковырять, может что пойму/увижу